# How do you change directories in a c program using environmental variables?

Tags: c, environment, setenv, cwd

I tried using `setenv("CWD", path, 1)`, but it keeps saying *implicit declaration* even though I included `stdlib.h`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the compiler warns about the "*implicit declaration*" of [`setenv()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) and not of `path` you need to make the prototype to [`setenv()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) available to the compiler by `#define`ing one of the following:

```
_BSD_SOURCE
```

or

```
_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L
```

or

```
_XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600
```

---

Also you cannot set the current work directory by setting the environment variable `CWD`. Use  [`chdir()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) instead.

Comment: Isn't chdir a system call, though?

Comment: @user3828080: Yes, `chdir` is an IX'ish system command also, why are you asking? Did you check `chdir()`'s documentation I linked in my answer?